# Call the onclick function from JQuery with parameters

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I am using a store locator jquery plugin from http://www.bjornblog.com/web/jquery-store-locator-plugin for my website and everything works fine but what I want to add is once the store location list is generated, the first one on the list is automatically clicked.

In the Jquery, I can see there is a section controlling the click on the list. It has some parameters.

```
// Handle clicks from the list          
$(document).on('click.'+pluginName, '.' + _this.settings.locationList + ' li', function () {
//do the work.
}
```

The pluginName is 'storelocator' and _this.settings.locationList is 'bh-sl-loc-list'

the elements of the list shown on the html

```
<div class="bh-sl-loc-list">
  <ul class="list list-unstyled"></ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>   
</div>
```

I tried the belows but obviously nothing worked, what sort of syntax I should use to maybe pass the parameters and call it? Much appreciated.

```
document.getElementById(".bh-sl-loc-list:first-child").onclick();
$('.bh-sl-loc-list:first-child').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to trigger the event bind on the element li.

Maybe you could try it like this:

```
$('.bh-sl-loc-list li:first-child').trigger('click.pluginName');
```

Or:

```
$('.bh-sl-loc-list ul li:first-child').trigger('click.pluginName');
```

Comment: didn't work, I am frustrated. I suspect $('.bh-sl-loc-list li:first-child').trigger('click.pluginName'); is very close.   I did if a condition it did return first li, but just cant click on it...

Comment: I have tried $('.bh-sl-loc-list li:first-child').trigger('click.storeLocator'); at one of the lib's example and it works well.

Comment: I guess in your situation maybe the trigger occur before the list's event has been bind.

Comment: Hi Li xiaojun, thanks a lot!!! i put it in a wrong place. I tried directly after the document()... and it worked!!! save my day!

Comment: just curious anyway, where did you add the line of code?

Comment: I tried to add the trigger code after the form(of bootstrap example) has been submitted, but I couldn't find where the form submission is handled. 
Actually, I only made it work from the browser's console.

Answer (score 1):

The event binding has a namespace, you need to include that in your `trigger` call.

```
$('.bh-sl-loc-list:first-child').trigger('click.pluginName');
```

Replace `pluginName` with the actual name of the plugin (whatever is in its internal variable `pluginName`).

Comment: I tried but didn't work, $(function() {
        $('#map-container').storeLocator({
        'dataType': 'json',
        'dataLocation': '../wp-content/themes/subway-clone/data/locations.json'
  
      });
 $('.bh-sl-loc-list:first-child').trigger('click.storelocator');   
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click' , pluginName, '.' + _this.settings.locationList + ' li', function () {
//do the work.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
document.getElementById("bh-sl-loc-list:first-child").click();
```

Comment: I did and no reply :(